# base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type error

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I got the error

" src/Graphics.cpp:29:32: erreur: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector’
 "

on the following code :

Constructor :

```
Graphics::Graphics()
{
 this->app = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 800, 32), "La Zapette !", 
               sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

  sf::Image img;
  img.LoadFromFile("./res/grass.jpg");

  for (int i = 0; i != 16; i++)
   {
      this->map.push_back(new sf::Sprite());
      this->map.back()->SetImage(img);
      this->map.back()->SetPosition(sf::Vector2f(0, 50 * i));
      this->app->Draw(this->map->back());
   }
   this->app->Display();  
}
```

Class :

```
class                   Graphics
{
private:
  sf::RenderWindow          *app;
  std::vector<sf::Sprite*>      map;
public:
  Graphics();
  ~Graphics();
  Event                 getEvent();
};
```

When i put a dot instead an arrow after the .back() method it doesnt compile.

Thanks

Comment: Next time you get a compiler error, please call out which line of the code you post corresponds to the error. For instance, I'm guessing line 29 corresponds to `this->app->Draw(this->map->back());`? But why should I have to guess, when you already know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
this->app->Draw(this->map->back());
```

Should be:

```
this->app->Draw(*(this->map.back()));
```

`map` is a `vector`, so its members should be accessed with `.` instead of `->`.
`Draw` takes a `const Drawable&`, so the pointer in the `vector` should be dereferenced.

Comment: Actually : this->app->Draw(*(this->map.back()));

Comment: Roman Grout: You were passing a pointer in the original code, so I did the same. I updated my answer with the corrected calling.

Answer (score 1):

It is **extremely helpful** to post full error messages and examples that other folks can compile on their own machines.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace sf {
    struct Image {
        void LoadFromFile(std::string);
    };

    struct Vector2f {
        Vector2f(float, float);
    };

    struct VideoMode {
        VideoMode(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned);
    };

    struct Sprite {
        void SetImage(Image);
        void SetPosition(Vector2f);
    };

    struct Style {
        static const unsigned Close = 1;
        static const unsigned Titlebar = 2;
    };

    struct RenderWindow {
        RenderWindow(VideoMode, std::string, unsigned);
        void Draw(Sprite *);
        void Display();
    };
}

class Event {
};

class Graphics
{
    private:
        sf::RenderWindow *app;
        std::vector<sf::Sprite*> map;
    public:
        Graphics();
        ~Graphics();
        Event getEvent();
};

Graphics::Graphics()
{
    this->app = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 800, 32), "La Zapette !", 
            sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

    sf::Image img;
    img.LoadFromFile("./res/grass.jpg");

    for (int i = 0; i != 16; i++)
    {
        this->map.push_back(new sf::Sprite());
        this->map.back()->SetImage(img);
        this->map.back()->SetPosition(sf::Vector2f(0, 50 * i));
        this->app->Draw(this->map->back());
    }
    this->app->Display();  
}
```

This code produces the error:

```
c++     foo.cc   -o foo
foo.cc:61:34: error: member reference type 'std::vector<sf::Sprite *>' is not a pointer; maybe you meant
      to use '.'?
        this->app->Draw(this->map->back());
                        ~~~~~~~~~^~
                                 .
1 error generated.
make: *** [foo] Error 1
```

Notice that the error message has included the line that the error is on. This is very helpful because you certainly didn't post 29 lines of code.

Depending on the signature of `Draw()`, this line should be one of:

```
this->app->Draw(this->map.back());
this->app->Draw(*(this->map.back()));
```